# JAVAFX - Returning to previous scene

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I am finding it difficult to find any tools or any information on the Internet, related to changing scenes in JAVAFX. For instance, I want to have multiple scenes and to be able to go to a next scene(frame where something will be happening) and when I finish my work in the 2nd scene, I would like to get back to the initial scene(frame) but I have no clue where to start from! If anyone could help me to get started, with any ideas that you think might help me to get a rough idea of how to approach this problem, I would really appreciate it! Thanks! :)

Comment: By "changing scene", do you mean changing the focus of the application?

Comment: A simple example for changing the scene would be the normal login screen you have when registering for a certain application. You are redirected to another scene(frame in Java Swing) when you don't have a username and have to register. I want to make my application working in a similar way, but whenever a user decides to go back(as you may have with the registration example), let's say, you've realised you have a username and would like to go back to the initial scene and just register, how should that be implemented? @fge